# Google project not visible in Developers Console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-console

I have created a Google project some time ago. The application can be found in appengine.google.com (and I can run it like this: [my-app-id].appspot.com) But I can not find it in https://console.developers.google.com/project I even tried to access it by typing the URL like this: https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~[my-app-id] which just gives "ERROR The project you requested is unavailable" I have not deleted the project.

How can I access the console pages. The problem is that I can not access the project's permissions (OAuth keys) without the console.

Any advice for this?

Comment: Hi JariK, I'm a Googler on the Console team.  Would you be willing to send me your app ID and the address of the Google account you're using, so I can look into this specific case?  My email address is in my SO profile.  Thanks!

Comment: At the bottom of the "Application Settings" page in the appengine control-panel, there's a "Cloud Integration" section with a button that should create one of the new-style "projects" for your app.

Comment: Thanks Greg (and Dan) that "new project" button in the Application Settings did the trick!

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Google Project Not visible in developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42465282/3744182).

Answer (score 14):

I've hit this a couple of times before remembering the solution which for me was to enable the "Google Play Android Developer API" in the Google API Console. Via Library > Mobile APIs > Google Play Android Developer API and you should see an Enable button at the top of the page.

Going back and refreshing the Google Play **Developer** Console now shows the API Console Project for linking.

---

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to the OP... sorry if I'm missing something. Enabling the "Google Play Android Developer API" in the Google API Console did not solve this for me. I still get `Listed 0 items` in response to `gcloud projects list` despite being able to see that the same account (with which I'm logged into SDK) is `Owner` on at least 1 project. when I specify that project with `gcloud projects describe project <project-id-1234567890>` it is described correctly. So it seems that the SDK is able to see the project, but decides not to list it. This is confusing behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

That project was so called legacy project, which needed to be "updated" in the Application Settings https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#cloudintegration, which is archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140403201059/https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#cloudintegration) and stated (in 2014):

> **Cloud Integration**
>
> New applications are automatically created with a Cloud project, which is required if your App Engine app needs to work with other Cloud products or use other Google APIs. However, older legacy App Engine apps were not created with a Cloud project. To create a Cloud project for these older legacy apps, you can use the App Engine Admin console's **Application Settings** page. This page has a Cloud Integration section with a **Create** button you can use to create a Cloud project for your app; it also creates a default Google Cloud Storage bucket for your optional use.