# Google Project Not visible in developer console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I was using one google project for GCM service previously. Now I need to enable firebase under the same project, However when I went into the account to update the config. It is not showing the Android apps which I was using previously. There 2 to 3 apps I was using, now those are not appearing in google console. Strange thing is that project is still working I can get the registration token as well for push notification but I can not see the project in developer console. Anyone faced the issue? Kindly help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25830194/7012517   have you tried this..?

Comment: yes, it didn't help

Comment: Hi faiziii. Are you still experiencing this? Are the projects also not visible from the Firebase Console?

Comment: Hi, Contacted to firebase support. Somehow my apps were deleted. Now created new apps

Answer (score 63):

For anyone facing the same problem as I faced (and the project didn't get deleted for any reason as in faizii case).

You just need to enable the project on Google Cloud Console through the following steps:

1) Go to [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home) and select your project.

2) From the "Navigation Menu" Select "APIs & Services" then select "Library".

[image: step 1]

3) Go to the Mobile section and select Google Play Android Developer API.

[image: step 2]

Or in Search box type Google Play Android Developer API as shown.

[image: step 3]

4) Click the "Enable" button, to enable the project in  Google Play Console.

[image: step 4]

5) Go to API access by navigating to Google Play Console -> Settings -> Developer Account then you should see the project listed.

[image: step 5]

6) After that, you can click on the "Link" project button to connect the project to the Google Play Console. Then you can use the API Access as you want.

Comment: Wouldn't have found that in a million years. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant thanks - would you mind editing your answer to remove the word "Just". There's nothing trivial about this if you don't already know... ;)

Comment: Has the API access screen been removed? I am unable to see it even when viewing the Play Console with the account owner.